# Grafana getting empty response from Prometheus

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana

I'm using the following Docker Compose File to startup Prometheus and Grafana:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  prometheus:
    build: ~/programming/tools/prometheus-2.39.1.linux-amd64
    ports: 
      - "9090:9090"
  alertmanager:
    build: ~/programming/tools/prometheus-2.39.1.linux-amd64/alertmanager
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

I'm able to ping the prometheus container from within the grafana container.

But i'm unable to configure the Prometheus Datasource in the Grafana UI.
I always get an `empty response` in the logs of grafana.

```
grafana_1     | logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin t=2022-12-02T06:33:08.707608032Z level=error msg="Internal server error" error="[plugin.downstreamError] failed to query data: received empty response from prometheus" remote_addr=172.18.0.1 traceID=
```

I'm thinking this could be because of the configured proxy. But i don't know how to set this in Grafana for the Datasource.
I have set the Proxysettings in the `~/.docker/config.json` file.

The strange thing is that i'm able to configure a different datasource like MySQL if i add a mysql container to the `docker-compose`

Comment: It's difficult to answer a question that's not a reproducible example. I took your `docker-compose.yml` and replaced `build` with pre-built images and am able to connect from Grafana to Prometheus using `http://prometheus:9090`

Comment: on a different machine without the proxy it works. So it seems like there is a problem with the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define `NO_PROXY` environment variable in Grafana's configuration and add Prometheus' URL to it.

Comment: Adding where in the configuraition as a code example would make this a better answer.